# How to extend the Rails' UJS functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to add some more functionality to the `jquery_ujs.js` file without altering its source code. I read the "[Rails jQuery UJS: now interactive](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-jquery-ujs-now-interactive/)" article but I did not understand how to make that since I am a JavaScript newbie.

In my `application.js` file I have the following handler-code in order to support the `data-custom-target` attribute:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('ajax:success',"a[data-custom-target]", function(xhr, data, status) {
    css_selector = $(this).data('custom-target');
    target = $("#" + css_selector);

    target.replaceWith(data);
  });
});
```

What I am trying to make is to add/extend the [`jquery_ujs.js`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) for supporting the `data-custom-target` attribute as-like made in that file for `linkClickSelector`, `buttonClickSelector` and so on.

How can I make that? Is it dangerous? What do you advice?

Comment: We have stuff like this all over our code base. Looks good to me

Comment: @ilan berci - In the question there is just an example. In general, how can I extend the Rails' UJS functionality?

Comment: @Michal Szyndel - The same as in my previous comment.

Comment: You can use  Jquery's extend() if you want to expose it to other teams/clients/etc.. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/